# How to find out where 2 queries would return different results

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have just fixed a query that was using the wrong column to find the most recent row by a certain user:

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM AUDIT_TABLE 
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :someId AND USER_NAME = :someUser AND ROWNUM=1 
ORDER BY THE_WRONG_COLUMN DESC
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM AUDIT_TABLE 
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :someId AND USER_NAME = :someUser AND ROWNUM=1 
ORDER BY SEQUENTIAL_ROW_ID DESC
```

Can I run a query to determine all Product_IDs that woud give a different result between the 2 queries for a single user?

Comment: You'd have to give more details, but I suspect that neither query is actually returning what you are expecting.  In both your queries, the `rownum` condition is applied ***before*** the `order by`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly, neither of these queries is doing what you think it's doing.  Both are getting an arbitrary first row that matches the `product_id` and `user_name` and then sorting that single row by either `the_wrong_column` or by `sequential_row_id`.  Since sorting a single row, by definition, can't impact the order of results, the `order by` in both cases is pointless.

If your intention is to get the row that meets your `product_id` and `user_name` criteria and then get the row with the largest `sequential_row_id`, you need to do the sort in an inline view and only then apply the `rownum` predicate

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM audit_table
         WHERE product_id = :something
           AND user_name  = :somethingElse
         ORDER BY sequential_row_id)
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

In general, you can compare the results of two queries using a `MINUS` to see the rows that one query returned that a different query did not.  If your queries were getting the rows you expected them to, I'd suggest doing something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               row_number() over (partition by product_id, user_name
                                       order by bad_column) rn
          FROM audit_table)
 WHERE rn = 1
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               row_number() over (partition by product_id, user_name
                                       order by sequential_id_column) rn
          FROM audit_table)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

That will show every row that the bad query would return that the good query would not.  You could reverse the `MINUS` to see everything that the good query would return that the bad query would not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use the `MIUNS` Function, its like `EXCEPT` in SQL Server

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   table_a
MINUS
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   table_b
```

This is a primitive example. You're basically selecting the first query and removing anything that the second query came up with, resulting in the difference